# Very simple method with QtConcurrentRun and mutex sometimes gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, thread-safety

I want to know what is wrong with this code. Sometimes I get sementation fault, sometimes not. This is a problem that I have in a greater piece of software, the idea is that just one thread at the same time is executing the method MyClass::print. Even with this simple example, it fail with segmentation fault. What is wrong in the code? How I can solve the problem?

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QtConcurrentRun>

class MyClass : QThread {
public:
    void print(std::string str) {
        mutex.lock();
        std::cout << "In some thread: " <<  str << "\n";
        mutex.unlock();
    }

private:
    QMutex mutex;

};

int main() {

    MyClass myCl;

    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        QtConcurrent::run(&myCl, &MyClass::print,std::string("bla"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with *this* code?

Comment: yes, with this code the problem occurs. I run it a couple of times and sometimes I get segmentation faults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not join your threads after the `for` cycle that spawns them.

Therefore, the `main()` function may end before all the threads have finished. This would make `myCl` go out of scope, and the threads would be trying to access an object that has been destroyed (in particular, its `mutex` variable). Which gives you **Undefined Behavior**.

Things should get better if you joined your threads before exiting from `main()` (or find any other way of not exiting from `main()` as long as any of the threads is still running).